# Preformance issue AutomationID attached property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have question about performance issue with `AutomationID` attached property. Is it using as much of Cpu and RAM as `Name` attribute, which is generally not recommended to supply if not needed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic DependencyProperty and the cost is not that great IMO.

I personally recommend to put it only on the key controls of your application which will be the target of ui tests.

Maybe you'll find this post useful too: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/11/03/coded-ui-tests-automationid-or-how-to-find-the-chose-one-control/