# Will adding AutomationProperties.AutomationId to a silverlight or wpf application cause a performance degradation? Or where should I go to look/check?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, automation, accessibility

There's a pretty hefty web app at my company that uses silverlight, and I want to add some accessibility tags to it such as "AutomationProperties.AutomationId" in the XAML

What I am curious about is whether adding these attributes to the various controls will cause any significant performance degradation. It seems like a rather hard thing to test and I can't find any documentation stating whether there are performance concerns.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Somebody told me a bit ago that all SL Controls cannot be made accessible. I can't find the list on MSDN, but you may be able to or it might have been old news

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this forum thread out:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/af88a252-adb0-4f14-a123-9b5b78a37a6e

It seems that the general consensus is that no, there should be no noteworthy performance degradation from using AutomationProperties.AutomationId.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but there really isn't enough info there to sway me either way. It just says no one knows lol Crap, I'll actually have to be an engineer and figure this shiz out.

Comment: I agree it's far from a definitive source, but both users thought it wasn't a huge issue. Here's another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628645/preformance-issue-automationid-attached-property